# Jenkins doesnt automatically trigger the pipeline when a new tag is pushed

Tags: jenkins, gitlab, cicd

I have a jenkins pipeline, and I simply want to trigger the pipeline whenever a tag is created, currently, jenkins detects the newly created tag, but I still need to build it manually!
My pipeline looks like the following:

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        node {
            label 'some-label'
        }
    }
    stage('core pipeline') {
         when {
            tag "*"
         }
         // do something
    }
```

I am using Gitlab as  source code repository.

Anything I am missing here?

Comment: You have mentioned nothing about the rest of the infrastructure. DevOps, GitLab, GitHub, etc...

Comment: I guess those are the only needed infos arent they? It's something quite related to jenkins! Would it help if I said I am hosting jenkins node on EC2 for example?

Comment: Well I know for a fact that Jenkins doesn't play nice with Azure DevOps unless you have you have a specific, deprecated, plugin enabled on Jenkins which then can communicate with it

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled correct [triggers](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#triggers) (In this case Polling?)

```
triggers { pollSCM('H */4 * * 1-5') }
```

Comment: Tag names are not supported as the branch argument.

Comment: Triggers are about doing cron checks where jenkins see if there are any changes and react accordingly, while my point is to trigger the build automatically whenever a new tag is added ! ( unless i am missing smth about triggers )

Comment: @MBA, Jenkins can't magically know that you have created tags. So there are two ways for Jenkins to know, 1. Jenkins Polls and check whether there are changes(Unless there are changes the Build will not run). 2. Gitlab tells Jenkins that a new Tag was created. (You need to configure a Webhook trigger in this case, there are different ways to do this, here is one option https://plugins.jenkins.io/generic-webhook-trigger/)